# What is "vocabulary" in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request

Having read [the recent meta discussion](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/263/79) concerning the tag [vocabulary](/questions/tagged/vocabulary) and remembering that [we prefer to have our tags in Latin](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/80/79), I started to wonder how one might translate the word "vocabulary" in Latin.
What would be a good translation and why?
I want to translate it in the context of tagging on this site.
That is, if someone wants to learn Latin vocabulary, how could they describe their desire in Latin using a word or phrase that means "vocabulary"?

The obvious choice is *vocabularium* and it would make sense as a derivative, but it's not in Lewis and Short.
A similar word, [*glossarium*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DG%3Aentry+group%3D11%3Aentry%3Dglossarium), can be found, but it seems to have an unsuitable nuance: [*glossa*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DG%3Aentry+group%3D11%3Aentry%3Dglossa) means "an obsolete or foreign word that requires explanation".
My current preference is *vocabularium* (cf. [*vocabulum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DV%3Aentry+group%3D25%3Aentry%3Dvocabulum) in L&S), but I'm not at all convinced that this is the optimal choice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the tag should remain in English for clarity's sake. Phrases like *copiae verborum* means more "one's personal vocabulary" rather than a discussion of, dare I say, specific words. "Vocabulary" for our sense, for the tag's sense, isn't really that.

Were we to go ahead and have a Latin word for it, *index verborum* would be understood. Other Romans chose Greek words, like *glossarium* (Gell. 18.7), *thesaurus* (Plin. praef. § 17), or *onomasticon*. I think *glossarium* or *onomasticon* would work best, with the former having a nice visual metaphor: as glossaries were used to "translate" obscure Latin words, so we here explain Latin words that a user might not understand.

Comment: Interesting that the only single-word choices come from Greek. @JoonasIlmavirta, this connects with our discussion about choosing between Greek words and Latin words.

Comment: @ktm5124 I'm not 100% sure, but I think tagging people who haven't responded yet aren't pinged.

Comment: Ah, good to know.

Comment: This answer best addresses the specific question about the tag, so I will accept this one. I too now find it best not to translate the tag to Latin. If someone creates such tags, they should be synonymized and we should leave [tag:vocabulary] as the main tag name. The others are useful, too. (I didn't see @ktm5124's ping.)

Answer (score 12):

The word 'vocabulary' is derived from *vocabulum*, meaning a word specific to some particular thing, as distinct from *verbum*, which is the word in general, and *dictum*, the spoken word.

Cicero (*de Oratore* 3.XXXI.125) clearly uses *copia verborum* to mean 'vocabulary':

*rerum copia verborum copiam gignit.*

Comment: Thanks! *Copia verborum* might indeed work. There is a broad problem that no Latin word seems to mean exactly "word", but they all have other tones (modern or ancient): *verbum* (also "verb"), *vox* (also "voice"), *dictum/scriptum* (only refers to one medium), *vocabulum* (as you mention). There is a danger of confusion if used on this site (the tag is not only for verbs), but in other contexts *copia verborum* is now my first option.

Answer (score 5):

I think the simplest choice is just the neuter plural *verba*. There's no reason to stick too closely to the English *vocabulary* and look for a singular noun with a collective meaning, which doesn't seem to exist in Latin. Questions tagged with [vocabulary](/questions/tagged/vocabulary) are those that are about (specific) words, as distinct from grammar etc., so in the context of the site, if you're asking such a question, you are asking about *verba*.

Comment: I suspect doing that would lead to confusion if "verbs" ever became a tag: *Aristoteles orationis duas partes esse dicit, vocabula et verba, ut homo et equus, et legit et currit...* This is one of the many problems in using the long dormant Latin for tags.

Comment: @cmw We already have the tag [tag:verbs]. But I would not translate that as *verba* either to avoid confusion.